# How to design a cosmos DB to do efficient query on non-partition key as well

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, partitioning, database-partitioning, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to Cosmos DB and facing issue in designing my DB.

I have a data similar to below structure

```
{
   "userId": "64_CHAR_ID",
   "gpId": "34_CHAR_ID"
   ... Other data
}
```

Currently my DB is having partition on userId as all the queries were by userId so far. Now I want to query my DB based on gpId when userId is not known. So it is ending up as cross partition query and it takes lot of clock-time(more than 5 min) and RUs (more than 3k RUs).

Query I am using is

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.gpId='SOME_GPID'
```

According to [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-query-container#avoiding-cross-partition-queries) we should avoid cross partition queries when dataset is large, and in my case the dataset is quite large (~80 GB).

So what would be a better design / strategy to query the data by gpId in cosmos db. My requirement is to query by gpId in almost real time.

**Note:** Current limit of RUs is set to 500000 RUs/s and also put on AutoScale.

Comment: FYI: I am removing the DynamoDB tag from this as it's not related to AWS at all - feel free to re-add in (with supporting information) if you think it is needed.

Comment: Please edit your question with more specifics. For example: what is "hell lot of time"? Is it a large number of RU? Is it clock-time? How much data do you have (what is "quite large"?) and what are your RU/sec settings? (depending on data quantity and performance needs, this is when you start having more physical partitions, which is where perf impacts could be, regarding cross-partition queries). What other filtering do you have in place in your query (e.g. WHERE clause) to make your query more efficient? As written, there's no way to answer your question objectively; just too many variables.

Comment: @DavidMakogon added the details as you requested. Please check it again and suggest a way. Also, as I am new to backend programming not sure if I need to put any more details or not. So please let me know if you need anything else as well.

Comment: @DavidMakogon any update?